# Securing SQL 2012 column data strategy

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, stored-procedures, encryption

I am working on a project that requires a column that is currently in plain text to be encrypted. As part of the project i still need to be able to run a SP from SSMS and the plain text data. I was going to go with the standard symmetric key encryption that is encrypted with an asymmetric key.

From the aspect of protecting the data from unwanted access, I'm not sure what the point of encrypting the data is if there is going to be an SP that is going to have all of the code to decrypt the column.

Is there a strategy for encrypting a single column, and protecting the data to ensure that if the DB is stolen then no one can access the encrypted data, even if they have access to the SP?

I know you can encrypt the SP's, but there are a lot of free tools to decrypt the SP's so I don't feel like that is a good strategy other than adding an extra step for someone to get through.

Comment: The symmetric key is ultimately protected by the Windows DPAPI so having access to the database alone will not be enough to decrypt. See   https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189586.aspx.

Comment: Ok. It sounds like I need to understand the Windows DPAPI process more. Just to clarify, so if someone took the DB and restored it on another system they wouldn't have access to the encrypted data, even if they got access to an administrator account?

Comment: Correct. They wouldn't have the SMK, and even if they did, they wouldn't have the SQL Server service account DPAPI used to protect it.

Comment: @ChandlerRReeves - have you considered [Transparent Data Encryption](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/encryption/transparent-data-encryption-tde)?  That protects the data at rest such that if a backup is stolen, the entire database is encrypted.  This method also means that no code-changes, such as the stored procedure you mention, need to be implemented.  The data is encrypted and decrypted by SQL Server as long as SQL Server has the encryption key.